# JavaScript library to decode PDF streams

Tags: javascript, pdf, compression, deflate

I'm looking for a JavaScript library to decode PDF streams. Is there any JS library that can do this easily?

Let's say that I know that the filter that will be used for the stream will be *FlateDecode*. Even then, I'm not able to decode the stream.

For example, I have a PDF that has this stream object:

```
10596 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<32A0A015231B6F4FB0DF3eB2E49EB691F><427BD1F9CB544B4B9916DDF475C70A50>]/Index[2334 1 2396 2 10594 3]/Info 2397 0 R/Length 33/Prev 1849582/Root 10480 0 R/Size 10597/Type/XRef/W[1 3 0]>>stream
hÞbb”ñÉfb``ð??Ó¯ Æ ®"ˆP??0=??Œ
endstream
endobject
```

I was trying to decode the stream using [pako](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00Fo8WZx8V5ZKMu8hq_ka2wgTnmgg%3A1600251270800&ei=huVhX7GuMMONlwSEypTQDQ&q=pako%20js&oq=pako%20js&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzICCAAyAggAMgQIABAKMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADIECAAQCjoECAAQRzoICAAQkQIQiwNQlswEWNrRBGCd0gRoAHABeAGAAZUCiAHsB5IBBTAuMi4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBB7gBAsABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwixibDEuO3rAhXDxoUKHQQlBdoQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) library. However, I get the following error: *ERROR incorrect header check*

I also see that the predictor function is used in this stream object. Is there any library that does the flate decoding that includes the predictor functions, or do I have to apply it separately?

EDIT: As *@Mark Adler* suggested I accidentally included line feeds into the bytes I was trying to decode. Now, that I corrected that I got a different error saying: *invalid distance too far back*

EDIT2:

Here's the relevant part of code:

```
const dict = pdfStr.slice(pdf.startXRef); // pdfStr contains the value of the whole PDF, pdf.startXRef holds the position of the the xref stream object
            const xrefStreamStart = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'stream', 1) + 'stream'.length + 2;
            const xrefStreamEnd = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'endstream', 1) - 1;
            const xrefStream = dict.slice(xrefStreamStart, xrefStreamEnd);
            console.log(this.strHex(xrefStream)); // logs the following value: 68de62621df1c966626060f00112d3af0009c60d20ae22c650020830003d0603520d
            const inflatedXrefStream = pako.inflate(xrefStream, { to: 'string' });
```

**EDIT3:** Here's the updated code that uses Uint8Array instead of string when parsing pdf.

```
const dict = pdfStr.slice(pdf.startXRef);
//pdf.stream.bytes holds the value of PDF as Uint8Array
        const pdfStreamDict = pdf.stream.bytes.slice(pdf.startXRef);
        const xrefStreamStart = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'stream', 1) + 'stream'.length + 2;
        const xrefStreamEnd = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'endstream', 1) - 2;
        const xrefStream = pdfStreamDict.slice(xrefStreamStart, xrefStreamEnd);
        console.log(this.buf2hex(xrefStream));
        const inflatedXrefStream = pako.inflate(xrefStream);
```

I finally managed to solve the problem using this approach, however when I tried same code on another PDF I got the error *incorrect header check* once again. Here' the hex value of parsed stream from that pdf: *9c636264e06760626038092498968258464082b10e44dc07117a4042e11a8815c2c0c4786b1948090323360200145f06*

Comment: Are you sure you're starting after the line feed? What are the first two bytes you are feeding to `pako.Inflate()`?

Comment: @MarkAdler Actually the line feeds were included, that's probably why I got this error. However, now that I changed the code to exclude the line feeds I got a different error: "invalid distance too far back"

Comment: Please update your question and provide the bytes in hex that you are feeding `pako.Inflate`. You also need to add the relevant portions of your code to the question. It sounds like you may be decoding UTF-8 or something like that, which you don't want to do. The deflate data in the PDF file must be treated as binary with no conversions of any kind.

Comment: If I remove the trailing carriage return (`0d`), that is a valid zlib stream, except for the distance too far back.

Comment: There must be some corruption due to using a javascript string to store the PDF. A javascript string tries to represent Unicode characters with two bytes per character. You should find a way to use `Uint8Array` instead of string.

Comment: Thank you. That was it, when I changed the code so, that the PDF is read as UInt8Array instead of string. It worked. Some bytes were indeed changed when PDF was parsed as string. Now, I need to find the way to handle the predictor function

Comment: You should add an answer to your own question, with the updated code that uses `UInt8Array`.